# create an index template using the java api in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The current java API for elastic search documentation does not say anything about creating an index template.
I know I can create an index template using crud, but my elastic search index is going grow depending on the data I get. The data I have right now, it may be possible that the data may change. So instead of manually making an index and a template, I want to know if it can be done through writing a code in Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the IndicesAdminClient to create a template

```
node.client().admin().indices().putTemplate(
    new PutIndexTemplateRequest("templatename").source(templateString)
);
```

PutIndexTemplateRequest has other methods to programatically build the template if you'd prefer to build it as a Java map, etc.

Comment: Is an index template created at Node level or cluster level?

Comment: @Vikash an index template is distinct from both cluster-settings and node-settings. You could consider it cluster-level, because it applies to all indices created in the cluster. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html